# (Windows Phone) Localizing App Title

Tags: localization, windows-phone-8

I have followed the [quick guide on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967550%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to localize my WP8 app title. Everything worked fine and I was able to see the localized app title from the emulator. However, ever since I added the C++ Win32 project (which was stated from the link above that it is a required project to perform localization), I am only able to build the project in x86 mode.

That is, even when I set in the Configuration Manager to compile for "All Platforms" it will still build for x86.

It didn't bother me too much until I try to run the app on my WP8 device. In which I got this error:

> Deployment failed because an app with target platform x86 cannot be
>   deployed to Device. If the target platform is win32/ x86, select an
>   emulator. If the target platform is ARM, select Device.

So naturally I tried to set the build configuration to ARM, and Visual Studio still builds the app in x86 mode. I'd figured it might due to the Win32 project added for localization.

That being said, I wish to understand if:

1. Will the app still work if I upload this to the marketplace?
2. Is there a way for me to be able to test it on an actual phone?

Thanks!

Comment: I am really not sure but I think that they said to use Win32 because the author of the article used it. This surely should be only a suggestion.
Have you tried using anything other than Win32?

Comment: Thanks, your answer did help me indirectly solve the problem. The problem was not due to the C++ project created, but due to another DLL reference. The problem has been fully resolved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem was caused by me trying to add a MarkedUp analytics reference to the project, and has nothing to do with the localization portion. I am sorry for the confusion. Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too, but I haven't made your mistake. I found out that after adding that C++ project my WP8 project was set to build for x86 architecture instead of 'AnyCPU'. I set it back to 'AnyCPU' and it fixed it.